# Creating piechart of text column from attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, chart

I would like to create a pie chart from a column of a attribute table, and I would like to see this pie chart above the map. The column contains names not numbers (I think fields aren't in a numeric format... on the other hand they're names!)
I work with marine species distribution data and I built a database of records of many many species...
In the specific, I have a column, called 'species', where there are many records (names) of some marine species. Several species may have many records, other species may have only a few numbers of records, so my objective is to graphically see the distribution of records among the species.
Please see the attachments:

- img1 http://postimg.org/image/rn56c8l4z/
- img2 http://postimg.org/image/e6918ynmj/

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this by opening the .dbf file with a spreadsheet program and making the pie chart in that program.  You can then save the pie chart as an image and add to the QGIS Composer window when you are ready to export your map.

Comment: Note: you can use the function 'countif(test_range; condition)' in excel or openoffice to count the number of times a string occurs in your cell range.  More infor here: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COUNTIF_function

Comment: Thank you: your solution is good but 'not dynamic'. I mean, the problem exposed above is part of a bigger one where I want to see the distribution of species over the years. In the specific I built a spatial grid in qgis, and inside each cell I can see the number of records-per-cell but I want aslo the number of species to avoid the problem to have only one species that makes all the records in a cell. In fact in my analysis the number of species in more important than the mere number of records...